# Number formatting in concatenation of sqldf in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I would like to understand the formatting, which is applied to a number, which is included in a concatenated string in `sqldf`.
I would like to know how one could replicate the output with base R, so basically it rounds to 0 digits, but prints out the first digit nonetheless.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT (' - tx: '||round(2152.918349)) as test")
           test
1  - tx: 2153.0
```

If I would just round this number using R without `sqldf`, it would just be printed out as an integer.

```
 print(round(2152.918349))
 [1] 2153
```

So most probably `sqldf` applies some additional formatting on the number, but I could not find any documentation on what exactly it is doing there.

Comment: It might be the SQLite round function, which does format the output like this. https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-round.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For base R to print the same number as `sqldf`, use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%.1f", round(2152.918349))

# [1] "2153.0"
```